# How to call INDEX values of an array in incremental manner in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, charts, increment

I am creating Stacked Bar chart Using Js library(dhtmlx).
Here is my Output: [image]

The json data is in following manner:

```
var data = [
    { "allocated":"20", "unallocated":"2", "day":"01/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"12", "unallocated":"0", "day":"02/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"2", "unallocated":"18", "day":"03/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"22", "unallocated":"2", "day":"04/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"3", "unallocated":"13", "day":"05/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"6", "unallocated":"2.4", "day":"06/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"6", "unallocated":"2.4", "day":"07/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"6", "unallocated":"2.4", "day":"08/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"6", "unallocated":"2.4", "day":"09/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"6", "unallocated":"2.4", "day":"10/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"6", "unallocated":"2.4", "day":"11/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"6", "unallocated":"2.4", "day":"12/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"6", "unallocated":"2.4", "day":"13/01/2014" },
    { "allocated":"14", "unallocated":"7", "day":"14/01/2014" },
];
```

However I managed to GroupBy my JSON data by **WEEK** 
by using following method:

```
var groupedByWeek = _.groupBy(data, function(item) {
    var dateMoment = moment(item.day,"DD/MM/YYYY");
    weeks = dateMoment.week();
    array = [weeks]
    return array;
});
```

Now, refer my uploaded Image, I am getting successfully data grouped by Week.
According to my given data i got 3 array indexes from it.

```
Object { 1: Array[4], 2: Array[7], 3: Array[3] }
```

Now I want to set index 1 as by default value for my graph. And then incrementally on "NEXT" button click, array index keeps on changing one by one.

In short i want to pass data week by week on X-axis. Is there any way to pass array index one by one? please help me.
thanks in advance.

whole code of my html file:

```
    <body>
    <div id="chart1" style="width:1020px;height:300px;border:0px solid #000000;">
        <div><a href="#">Next</a></div>
    </div>


<script>

    var barChart1 =  new dhtmlXChart({
        view:"stackedBar",
        container:"chart1",
        value:"#allocated#",
        label:"#allocated#",
        color: "#a24689",
        // gradient:"falling",
        width:40,
        tooltip:{
            template:"#allocated#"
        },

        xAxis:{
            title:"Days",
            template:"#day#",

        },

        yAxis:{
            title:"Hours",
            start:0,
            step:4,
            end:24
        },

        legend:{
            values:[{text:"Compeleted Activities",color:"#a24689"},{text:"Undefined",color:"#F9D544"}],
            valign:"top",
            align:"center",
            width:110,
            layout:"x"
        }
    });

    barChart1.addSeries({
        value:"#unallocated#",
        color:"#F9D544",
        label:"#unallocated#",
        tooltip:{
            template:"#unallocated#"
        }
    });

    var groupedByWeek = _.groupBy(data, function(item) {
        var dateMoment = moment(item.day,"DD/MM/YYYY");
        weeks = dateMoment.week();
        array = [weeks]
        return array;
    });
    console.log(groupedByWeek)

    barChart1.parse(data,"json");
    // console.log(data)

</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps you should take the data returned by your `groupedByWeek` operation, and construct a new json data-array from it, based on your chosen Index value.  Then pass THAT array to the `barChart1.parse()` operation.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked finally.

```
var groupedByWeek = _.groupBy(data, function(item) {
        var dateMoment = moment(item.day,"DD/MM/YYYY");
        return dateMoment.week();
```

The value of `groupedByWeek` is in array form.
It can be done by passing the index value of an array at `barChart1.parse(groupedByWeek[1],"json");` instead `barChart1.parse(data,"json");`

finally it worked!